# using sort command to sort by colums

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a simple data set. example:

IP address,number of times it appears

```
192.168.0.10,11
192.168.0.1,15
192.168.0.120,9
```

I want to use the sort command to sort these by the largest number of times the IP has been seen. the output should look like:

```
192.168.0.1,15
192.168.0.10,11
192.168.0.120,9
```

Comment: This question is both off-topic and shows no research effort.

Comment: I know its sort -k but after running "sort -k2" I still do not get the desired output.

Comment: man, those IP-sorting questions are zilion in SO. Please, try search.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-k` to specify the column. Don't forget about `-n` to use numeric ordering.

```
sort -n -k2 file.txt
```